# Join on Array Intersection

Tags: pyspark, hive

Hello I'd like to join on array intersection. I've found an arrays_overlap function on spark -- yet I cannot seem to get it to work. I've also tried writing a custom UDF to no avail. There error message I receive is "requires attributes from more than one child". I have no idea what that means making this hard to debug. Am I missing something basic about this? Using Hive/pyspark

Sample queries:

```
select
a.id
from tbl a
JOIN tbl_b b
ON arrays_overlap(a.my_arr, b.my_arr) = TRUE
```

```
def _arrays_overlap(a,b):
    for item in a:
        if item in b:
            return True
    return False

spark.udf.register(
    "_arrays_overlap",
    _arrays_overlap,
    BooleanType()
)


select
a.id
from tbl a
JOIN tbl_b b
ON _arrays_overlap(a.my_arr, b.my_arr) = TRUE
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: don't think you need `= TRUE` comparison in the join predicate. it is only evaluated on a `TRUE` condition. `arrays_overlap` already returns a `boolean`. be aware this is equivalent to a `cross join` where an array from one row is evaluated against all the other rows.

Comment: Thanks @VamsiPrabhala , and yes I originally wrote it as a cross join -- so was just trying to make it easier to read -- I'm thinking this has to be a versioning issue. But my dev env makes that hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

From **`Spark-2.4`**:

We can use `array_intersect` function with size to join only the rows size !=0.

- (or) `arrays_overlap` and joining on boolean `TRUE`

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,[1,2,3]),(2,[4,5])],["id","my_arr"])
df1=spark.createDataFrame([(1,[2,3]),(2,[8,9])],["id","my_arr"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl_b")

spark.sql("select a.id from tbl a join tbl_b b on arrays_overlap(a.my_arr,b.my_arr) = TRUE").show()

spark.sql("select a.id from tbl a join tbl_b b on SIZE(array_intersect(a.my_arr,b.my_arr)) != 0").show()

#+---+
#| id|
#+---+
#|  1|
#+---+
```

Comment: hm -- as you can see in the first example i tried the arrays overlap. Somewhat new to spark and this is operating on a hive table. Any idea why my custum UDF wouldn't work.